# Possible Vaadin bug: cannot navigate to root context path

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Spring 2.x and Vaadin 13 here. I created a GitHub repo to exactly reproduce an issue I'm seeing at app startup [here](https://github.com/bitbythecron/vaadin-troubleshooting), but essentially here's what's happening.

At app startup I'm seeing:

```
21:23:18.655 http-nio-9200-exec-2 [ERROR] org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver - Real error: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage. ServerContainer is null
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage. ServerContainer is null
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:53)
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

I prefer to use Jetty if at all possible, which is why I specify Jetty in my `build.gradle` file:

```
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:2.1.0.RELEASE'
```

I *feel* like this exception is coming from something container-related but can't peg it down. Normally I wouldn't be too concerned, but then if you go to the root context (`http://localhost:9200`) in a browser you get a strange error message:

```
Could not navigate to ''
Reason: Couldn't find route for ''

Available routes:
This detailed message is only shown when running in development mode.
```

Even though I have a view at that path:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@Route(value = "", layout = LoginLayout.class)
@ParentLayout(LoginLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Login")     // TODO: <--- i18n ???
public class LoginView implements View<LoginPresenter> {
    ...
}
```

**Any ideas where I'm going awry?**

Again the GitHub repo reproduces all of this entirely. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you would have an easier time using the DS Vaadin Flow Gradle plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.devsoap.vaadin-flow) for Vaadin integration and the Gretty plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gretty) for running and configuring Jetty.

Comment: You implicitly also include tomcat (via vaadin-starter -> sb web-starter -> sb tomcat-starter); removing that dep via an exclude eliminates the error with atmosphere

Comment: I can't answer your question but maybe help a bit... Do you have spring-devtools on the classpath? Because when I use it along-side Vaadin I usually lose the routes after a few reloads and start seeing the behavior you are describing. Sometimes I have to do a maven: clean to get it working again.